# Existe um tamanho padrão para o aumento da memoria do tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Olá, existe um tamanho padrão para o aumento da memoria do tomcat, através dos parâmetros XmX e XmS?

Comment: Esse "padrão" que citou é o que já está definido não? Você deseja aumentar?

Answer (score 2):

Existe sim um padrão recomendado para o aumento da memória do tomcat, como você sabe, o aumento é editando os parâmetros Xms e Xmx, que vão ser passados para a JVM no momento do startup do servidor. Com relação aos valores utilizados pela jvm, deve-se levar em consideração os seguintes detalhes:

1 - Valores passados para Xms(Alocação inicial de memória) e Xmx(Alocação máxima de memória)devem ser múltiplos de 1024.

- Xms o valor não deve ser menor que 1m, o padrão é 2m.
- Xmx o valor máximo é 2G em jvm's em arquitetura de 32 Bits, o padrão é 64m.

Os valores pode ser passados em bytes, kbytes e Mbytes no formato:

-Xms6291456

-Xms6144k

-Xms6m

2 - Para o Tomcat, uma boa regra para você adotar é a seguinte:

O valor máximo de memória(Xmx) deve ser igual ou o dobro do valor inicial (Xms);

Ex:

-Xms256m

-Xmx512m

Eu geralmente utilizo sempre o dobro.